# This site can’t be reached ERR_ACCESS_DENIED after submitting a form with an input file in Laravel 5.2

Tags: file, laravel, upload

I'm trying to upload a file but always get this after submit. Please help.

```
    This site can’t be reached
    The webpage at http://localhost:8000/update_profile_picture might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
    ERR_ACCESS_DENIED
```

Here's my code..

**in my form:**

```
<div class="select-profile-picture" id="update_profile_picture">
             <form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('update_profile_picture') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('profile_picture') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <input type="file" name="profile_picture" class="form-control">
                            @if ($errors->has('profile_picture'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('profile_picture') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update profile picture</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

**in routes.php**

```
Route::post('update_profile_picture', 'User\UserController@updateProfilePicture');
```

**in User\UserController.php**

```
public function updateProfilePicture(Requests\UpdateProfilePictureRequest $request) {
    // haven't done anything here yet but still gets the error after selecting a file and submitting it
    return 'working';
}
```

Comment: Can you show us `UpdateProfilePictureRequest`?

Comment: thank you for your response. i already fix the problem. i tried to use a different web browser and it works just fine. im using kali linux i think its because google chrome is running inside root user using a different chromeuser. but anyways im happy the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens because you are choosing a directory or folder in the input file field.